# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:

Tags: web-services, soapui

I got a wsdl from customer to consume. I am using soupUI tool for it. I got the request xml like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vmps="http://dynamicops.com/VMPS" xmlns:dyn="http://DynamicOps.VMPS.Model" xmlns:dyn1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DynamicOps.VMPS.Model" xmlns:dyn2="http://DynamicOps.Common.BaseModel">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <vmps:CreateVirtualMachineTemplate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <vmps:identityToken>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:ImpersonatingUser>?</dyn:ImpersonatingUser>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:User>?</dyn:User>
         </vmps:identityToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <vmps:template>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn1:ID>?</dyn1:ID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn2:Name>?</dyn2:Name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn2:Description>?</dyn2:Description>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:ApprovalPolicyId>?</dyn:ApprovalPolicyId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:BlueprintType>?</dyn:BlueprintType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:Cost>?</dyn:Cost>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:CpuCount>?</dyn:CpuCount>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:CpuCountMax>?</dyn:CpuCountMax>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:CreatedAt>?</dyn:CreatedAt>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:DeletedAt>?</dyn:DeletedAt>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:DiskSize0InGB>?</dyn:DiskSize0InGB>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:DiskSizeMaxGB>?</dyn:DiskSizeMaxGB>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:Enabled>?</dyn:Enabled>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:ExpireDays>?</dyn:ExpireDays>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:GlobalProfileID>?</dyn:GlobalProfileID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:Groups>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <dyn:GroupBase>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn1:ID>?</dyn1:ID>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn2:Name>?</dyn2:Name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn2:Description>?</dyn2:Description>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:AdministratorEmail>?</dyn:AdministratorEmail>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:GroupID>?</dyn:GroupID>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsTestGroup>?</dyn:IsTestGroup>
               </dyn:GroupBase>
            </dyn:Groups>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:IsGlobal>?</dyn:IsGlobal>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:IsMaster>?</dyn:IsMaster>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:LeaseDays>?</dyn:LeaseDays>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:LeaseDaysMax>?</dyn:LeaseDaysMax>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:MachinePrefix>?</dyn:MachinePrefix>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:MachineType>?</dyn:MachineType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:MaxVMsPerUser>?</dyn:MaxVMsPerUser>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:Members>?</dyn:Members>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:MemoryInMB>?</dyn:MemoryInMB>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:MemoryMaxMB>?</dyn:MemoryMaxMB>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:ParentID>?</dyn:ParentID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:RequiresApproval>?</dyn:RequiresApproval>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:ReservationPolicyID>?</dyn:ReservationPolicyID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:UpdatedAt>?</dyn:UpdatedAt>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:WorkflowID>?</dyn:WorkflowID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:WorkflowInfo>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn1:ID>?</dyn1:ID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn2:Name>?</dyn2:Name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn2:Description>?</dyn2:Description>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:AssemblyFQN>?</dyn:AssemblyFQN>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:BuildTagType>?</dyn:BuildTagType>
            </dyn:WorkflowInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:HiddenProperties>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <dyn:NameValue>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsEncrypted>?</dyn:IsEncrypted>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsHidden>?</dyn:IsHidden>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsRuntime>?</dyn:IsRuntime>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:Name>?</dyn:Name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:Value>?</dyn:Value>
               </dyn:NameValue>
            </dyn:HiddenProperties>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:LeaseCostFormatted>?</dyn:LeaseCostFormatted>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:Parent>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn1:ID>?</dyn1:ID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn2:Name>?</dyn2:Name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn2:Description>?</dyn2:Description>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:ApprovalPolicyId>?</dyn:ApprovalPolicyId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:BlueprintType>?</dyn:BlueprintType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:Cost>?</dyn:Cost>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:CpuCount>?</dyn:CpuCount>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:CpuCountMax>?</dyn:CpuCountMax>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:CreatedAt>?</dyn:CreatedAt>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:DeletedAt>?</dyn:DeletedAt>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:DiskSize0InGB>?</dyn:DiskSize0InGB>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:DiskSizeMaxGB>?</dyn:DiskSizeMaxGB>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:Enabled>?</dyn:Enabled>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:ExpireDays>?</dyn:ExpireDays>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:GlobalProfileID>?</dyn:GlobalProfileID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:Groups>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <dyn:GroupBase>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <dyn1:ID>?</dyn1:ID>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <dyn2:Name>?</dyn2:Name>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <dyn2:Description>?</dyn2:Description>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <dyn:AdministratorEmail>?</dyn:AdministratorEmail>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <dyn:GroupID>?</dyn:GroupID>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <dyn:IsTestGroup>?</dyn:IsTestGroup>
                  </dyn:GroupBase>
               </dyn:Groups>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:IsGlobal>?</dyn:IsGlobal>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:IsMaster>?</dyn:IsMaster>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:LeaseDays>?</dyn:LeaseDays>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:LeaseDaysMax>?</dyn:LeaseDaysMax>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:MachinePrefix>?</dyn:MachinePrefix>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:MachineType>?</dyn:MachineType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:MaxVMsPerUser>?</dyn:MaxVMsPerUser>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:Members>?</dyn:Members>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:MemoryInMB>?</dyn:MemoryInMB>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:MemoryMaxMB>?</dyn:MemoryMaxMB>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:ParentID>?</dyn:ParentID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:RequiresApproval>?</dyn:RequiresApproval>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:ReservationPolicyID>?</dyn:ReservationPolicyID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:UpdatedAt>?</dyn:UpdatedAt>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:WorkflowID>?</dyn:WorkflowID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <dyn:WorkflowInfo>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn1:ID>?</dyn1:ID>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn2:Name>?</dyn2:Name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn2:Description>?</dyn2:Description>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:AssemblyFQN>?</dyn:AssemblyFQN>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:BuildTagType>?</dyn:BuildTagType>
               </dyn:WorkflowInfo>
            </dyn:Parent>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <dyn:Properties>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <dyn:NameValue>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsEncrypted>?</dyn:IsEncrypted>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsHidden>?</dyn:IsHidden>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:IsRuntime>?</dyn:IsRuntime>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:Name>?</dyn:Name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <dyn:Value>?</dyn:Value>
               </dyn:NameValue>
            </dyn:Properties>
         </vmps:template>
      </vmps:CreateVirtualMachineTemplate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I am sending this request I am getting the response like

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://dynamicops.com/VMPS:template. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type DynamicOps.VMPS.Model.VirtualMachineTemplateEx. The value '?' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException>
                  <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                  <InnerException>
                     <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                     <InnerException>
                        <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                        <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                        <Message>Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).</Message>
                        <StackTrace>at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&amp; result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&amp; result)
   at System.Guid.Parse(String input)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()</StackTrace>
                        <Type>System.FormatException</Type>
                     </InnerException>
                     <Message>The value '?' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.</Message>
                     <StackTrace>at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsGuid()
   at ReadVirtualMachineTemplateExFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)</StackTrace>
                     <Type>System.Xml.XmlException</Type>
                  </InnerException>
                  <Message>There was an error deserializing the object of type DynamicOps.VMPS.Model.VirtualMachineTemplateEx. The value '?' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.</Message>
                  <StackTrace>at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)</StackTrace>
                  <Type>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</Type>
               </InnerException>
               <Message>The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://dynamicops.com/VMPS:template. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type DynamicOps.VMPS.Model.VirtualMachineTemplateEx. The value '?' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</Message>
               <StackTrace>at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
               <Type>System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Can anyone help me what is the issue??
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fill your request with values, where it is now marked with "?". The error message says that a field of GUID type contains an invalid value, and since your request is all "?" no valid GUID exists. Fill your request with decent values and the problem should go away.

A tutorial mentioning the question mark syntax is [here](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/testing-web-services-with-soapui)